# Communication between multiple markers and div background failed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to communicate between some Markers in a Google map and a few divs outside of the map. If I mouse over a marker in the map, I want to change the background color in a separate Div. If I got only one marker it works fine, but if I have five, like in the example, only the last one in the list will be displayed.

Why is that? What is wrong? Can someone help me?

```
function initialize() {
  var locations = [
    ['E021066', 39.521753693611515, 2.480292320251465, 4],
    ['E033012', 39.52724876810637, 2.48166561126709, 5],
    ['E023016', 39.50193802307746, 2.4660873413085938, 3],
    ['E019512', 39.522349566080855, 2.4886178970336914, 2],
    ['E032023', 39.510927787044295, 2.4994325637817383, 1]
  ];
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.5075442, 2.476614799999993);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var image1 = 'images/marker1.png';
  var image2 = 'images/marker2.png';
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    **var id = locations[i][0];**
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: image1
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        marker.setImage("images/marker.png");
      }
    })(marker, i));
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
      this.setIcon(image2);
      **id.style.backgroundColor='#ccc';**
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      this.setIcon(image1);
      **id.style.backgroundColor='#fff';**
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a common issue.  marker is a global variable, when the loop ends, it is left pointing to the last one created.  I would suggest using function closure (a createMarker function) to associate both the mouseover/out and click listeners to the marker.  Something like:

```
function createMarker(location)
{
  var id = location[0];
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image1
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      marker.setImage("images/marker.png");
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    this.setIcon(image2);
    id.style.backgroundColor='#ccc';
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    this.setIcon(image1);
    id.style.backgroundColor='#fff';
  });
}
```

Then your loop becomes:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  createMarker(locations[i]);
}
```

I wouldn't expect it to be working though except perhaps in IE.

[Working Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_mouseoverA.html)

Answer (score 0):

thank you, has worked fine, but only after I converted the ID string .

```
var locations = [
  [E021066, 39.521753693611515, 2.480292320251465, 0]
];
```

Now I have a last problem, I would also like to change the marker image when the user moves the mouse over the div, unfortunately I do not know how I am referring to the marker. Does anyone have any advice?

```
<div class="offer_box" id="E021066"><a href="#" onmouseover="createMarker['E021066'].setIcon('marker2.png')" onmouseout="createMarker['E021066'].setIcon('marker1.png')">
```

Comment: You should ask this in a separate question. :)